# Parametro no se pasa correctamente a una query nativa en JPA Spring Booot

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, spring-boot, jpa

Buen dia

Estoy desarrollando un backend en Spring Boot con JPA para el tema de las operaciones con base de datos. Mi problema radica en que el parametro que me llega del frontend, llega correctamente al metodo en el controller pero cuando lo envio del controller al repository, este ya no llega y el valor se pone como vacio en la Query Nativa.

Podrian indicarme que estoy haciendo mal? De antemano gracias

Formulario Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/getCountAnexos")
    @ResponseBody
    public String countAnexosRechazo(@RequestBody String responsableServicio) {
        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // Cambiar a nativeQuery

        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println(responsableServicio);
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        String respuesta = formularioRepository.getAnexosRechazados(responsableServicio);
        System.out.printf("RESPUESTA",respuesta);


        return respuesta;

    }
```

Formulario Repository

```
// Consulta para obtener el numero de Anexos Rechazados de acuerdo el Usuario
    @Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM formulario where year(fechaTramite)='2020' and responsableServicio = :responsableServicio and (estatusGestorContratos = 'Rechazado' or estatusAFTI = 'Rechazado')", nativeQuery = true)
    public abstract String getAnexosRechazados(@Param("responsableServicio") String responsableServicio);
```

Nota: pienso que llega vacio ya que me aparece un signo de ? en el valor del parametro, asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cómo sabes que llega vacío?

Comment: @E.Betanzos pues por que la consulta me regresa 0 registros cuando debe regresar 1. Ya que si pongo directamente el valor de resposableServicio en la query, si regresa el resultado correcto, osea 1

Comment: Que no obtengas el resultado esperado no quiere decir que el parámetro se pase vacío. El signo ? indica que en ese lugar se va a pasar el valor de un parámetro pero dicho valor nunca se muestra en los logs. Puedes agregar un ejemplo de la consulta que dices que funciona (agregando el valor manualmente)?